# Convert select column output into semi-colon seperated list for sp_send_dbmail

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a complex select statement (the union of several queries) which outputs a single column e.g.

```
| email            |
| test@domain.com  |
| test2@domain.com |
| test3@domain.com |
```

I would like to feed this into the @blind_copy_recipients of sp_send_dbmail which requires a semi colon (;) separated list.

would normally use COALESCE and a variable to accomplish this but you can't seem to do that with a statement with UNIONS.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Whilst typing this question is has occurred to me that a better way might be to use a  cursor to cycle through the records and send the messages individually but I'm still interested in the answer.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid cursors as much as possible.

In the meantime, try this:

```
DECLARE @blind_copy_recipients VARCHAR(4000) 
-- Or whatever is the suitable size you expect

SELECT @blind_copy_recipients = COALESCE(@blind_copy_recipients + ', ', '') + 
   CAST(BCC.BLIND_COPY_RECIPIENTS_UNION_OUTPUT_COLUMN AS VARCHAR(50)) 
    -- Again, change to suit your needs
FROM 
(
-- SELECT UNION SELECT UNION SELECT UNION --
) AS BCC

SELECT @blind_copy_recipients
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two methods:

1. Put the union result in a temporary table.
2. Use the COALESCE.

or

1. Use the result union as a sub query.
2. Use the COALESCE on it.

Comment: Perhaps there's no need to utilize a temp table if you can grab it from the union if treated like a subquery... Or is grabbing from a subquery more expensive?

Comment: @Nonym you are right, I've editted the answer. It could be, depending on how "vast" the subquery is.

Answer (score 1):

Stick the selects in a CTE?

```
declare @addr varchar(1024) = ''
;with T(addr) as (
    select email from emails where id = 1
    union
    select email from moreemails where id = 1
    ...
)
select @addr += case @addr when '' then '' else ';' end + addr from T
```

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL you can use `COALESCE` like this

```
declare @result nvarchar (max)
set @result = ''

select @result = coalesce (
                   case when @result = ''
                   then YourColumnName
                   else @result + ',' + YourColumnName
                   end
                 ,'')
from dbo.YourTableName

print @result
```

Answer (score 0):

[They are severalt methods to achieve this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/). 'The blackbox XML methods' is one of them, here a templeate:

```
SELECT p1.CategoryId,
          ( SELECT ProductName + ',' 
              FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p2
             WHERE p2.CategoryId = p1.CategoryId
             ORDER BY ProductName
               FOR XML PATH('') ) AS Products
      FROM Northwind.dbo.Products p1
     GROUP BY CategoryId ;
```

**For your schema**:

```
SELECT email + ',' 
  FROM yourComplexQuery p2
   FOR XML PATH('') ;
```

Here a sample: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120618/

Answer (score -1):

You can store Union result in a temp table.